# How can i scale an image with (moz/webkit/etc) while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im trying to do this i just cant figure out how to any ideas?

Dont pay attention to the parallax just wanna know how to scale the image while im scrolling(if the scroll goes up make the image smaller and when it goes down bigger)

www.smartusa.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use scrollorama to set up positions and configure when the different sizes should be shown.

http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/

Comment: tnx this is really useful im just having some problems with the configuration but it looks really good! Ill keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

Using the scroll position requires JavaScript, if I'm not mistaken.

​Just execute a piece of code on scrolling that sets the image size: http://jsfiddle.net/TwLuE/.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var s = Math.min(400, $(document).scrollTop()) + 100;
    $("img").width(s).height(s);
});​
```

Comment: for some reason it says $(window).on is not a function          <script src="js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var s = Math.min(400, $(document).scrollTop()) + 100;
    $("img").width(s).height(s);
});

Comment: @Buff: For 1.5, it's .bind rather than .on.

Comment: tnx alot for the help guys :)!